# How to open more than one location of the same file, edit it and save it

Tags: notepad++

I have a long python file (~6000 lines) which I have to edit at two places: one at the top and the other near the middle of lower part.
Presently, I have only the following options:

1. scroll up and down to make changes whenever required
2. copy the top part which i edit to a separate file and open it in the "Other View" of Notepad++. Once all editing is done, copy that part back to the top of the original file
3. Open a real time collaboration supporting multi user editor like google doc and open the same file in two windows and edit its two parts

What is the best way to open more than one location of the same file, edit it and save it

I have heard that this could be done in [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) but i would prefer a Notepad++ based solution if possible
I have Notepad++ v6.5.3

Comment: What's wrong with opening the source file, and then simply using `View->Clone to other view` to split the window?

Comment: Thanks Ken.. I tried it just now and it worked.. I should have tried that option earlier before posting this question.. I just googled multi editing, multiple location editing, etc in notepad++ but could not get the hints..

Comment: Hey Ken.. Could you pl post the above comment as an answer so that I can "accept" it

Comment: Done. :-) It's a very useful capability in NP++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your source file, and then use `View->Move/Clone Current Document->Clone to other view` to split the window into two separate panes.

[image: Notepad++ With Two Views of Source File]